# Perl: Why does \@_ provide an alias to the passed in array?

Tags: perl

This is a follow up to the question posted here: [How do I take a reference to an array slice in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817373/how-do-i-take-a-reference-to-an-array-slice-in-perl)

```
sub getArrayRef { return \@_ }

my @arr = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
my $sub_arr = getArrayRef(@arr[1..2]); # Changes made to $sub_arr->[0] reflect in $arr[1]
```

I just want to know why this works. The author of the post said it works due to "aliasing magic," but I have no idea what that means.

This method is different from trying to take the reference from the slice:

```
my @arr = (0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
my $sub_arr = \@arr[1..2]; # array of references rather than aliases to elements of @arr
```

What's special about `@_` that `\` makes it return aliases to the variable instead of references?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Aliasing magic" means that Perl plays several tricks to be as fast as it can. One of those tricks is to alias values instead of copying them. The values in `@_` are not copies so Perl doesn't have to move data around for a very common operation that probably happens frequently.

This is also true in other situations, including the loop variable for `foreach`:

```
use v5.10;

my @items = qw( a b c );
say "items: @items";

foreach my $item ( @items ) {
    $item = uc($item);
    }

say "items: @items";
```

By changing the control variable, you actually change the original:

```
items: a b c
items: A B C
```

To get around this, don't modify the control variables, `@_`, and some other things that perl gives you. The trick that Eric is using in [How do I take a reference to an array slice in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817373/how-do-i-take-a-reference-to-an-array-slice-in-perl) is something you should avoid simply because it will confuse everyone, including future you.

Comment: Is there not a good use case for this? I have a byte array that contains different sets of data. I use it like so: `$this_data = getArrayRef(@byte_array[8..15]); $that_data = getArrayRef(@byte_array[16..19])`. I want to modify this byte array and then replace the original array. It was a bit easier to modify references of the array than trying to split at different boundaries and putting it back together in the same order. Maybe it makes more sense to me because I'm a C++ programmer where I would have taken a reference to the array like `&byte_array[8]` and then processed 8 bytes.

Comment: No idea about "good". You asked what the aliasing magic was, and my answer is limited to that. But, Perl isn't C++ either. I sounds like you want splice.

Answer (score 2):

The following are equivalent:

```perl
getArrayRef( @arr[ 1 .. 2 ] )
```

```perl
getArrayRef( $arr[ 1 ], $arr[ 2 ] )
```

And [perlsub](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub) tells us the following:

> `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters.

As such, the following are also equivalent:

```perl
do {
   use experimental qw( refaliasing );
   local @_;
   \$_[ 0 ] = \$arr[ 1 ];
   \$_[ 1 ] = \$arr[ 2 ];
   &getArrayRef
}
```

```perl
do {
   use experimental qw( refaliasing );
   local @_;
   \$_[ 0 ] = \$arr[ 1 ];
   \$_[ 1 ] = \$arr[ 2 ];
   \@_
}
```

```perl
do {
   use experimental qw( refaliasing );
   my @a;
   \$a[ 0 ] = \$arr[ 1 ];
   \$a[ 1 ] = \$arr[ 2 ];
   \@a
}
```

So,

The first element of the new array (`$_[ 0 ]`/`$sub_arr->[ 0 ]`) is an alias of second element of the pre-existing array (`$arr[ 1 ]`), so any changes to one will change the other.

The first element of the new array (`$_[ 1 ]`/`$sub_arr->[ 1 ]`) is an alias of second element of the pre-existing array (`$arr[ 2 ]`), so any changes to one will change the other.

Answer (score 1):

As documented in [perlsub](https://perldoc.pl/perlsub)

> `@_` is a local array, but its elements are aliases for the actual scalar parameters.

Therefore, the elements of `@_` in this case contain the sliced elements of the array. You return a reference to the array.

So, there's nothing special about `\`, but the `@_` is "magical".

Comment: I still don't understand. Why wouldn't that make it be an array of references? If @_ has $_[0] and $_[1], why doesn't \@_ return \$_[0] and \$[1] like \@arr would return \$arr[0] and \$arr[1] (i.e. references to the individual elements of the array)

Comment: @Warpstar22: It wouldn't.

Comment: ``\`` is distributed over a list, not over array elements.

Comment: @Warpstar22, Re "*Why wouldn't that make it be an array of references?*", `@_` is an array of aliases, and `\@_` produces a reference to an array of aliases.